# Y is complete then so $L(X,Y)$

Tags: real-analysis

the question has been asked on the exchange([If Y is complete then B(X,Y) is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241816/if-y-is-complete-then-bx-y-is-complete)) but none of them necessarily have a clearly answer for the question I have for one part.

When we show $\|T_n-T\|\to 0$. The proof often involves the following inequality

\begin{align}
\|T_nx-Tx\|&\leq \|T_n-T_m\|\|x\|+\|T_mx-Tx\|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2
\end{align}

It seems all explanation relating to $\|T_mx-Tx\|<\epsilon/2$ is first note the above inequality holds for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$ (due to cauchy citerion), fix such m, $\|T_m-Tx\|<\epsilon/2$. But I am still confused on why can we locate a $m$ that guarantees $T_m$ is epsilon close to $T$?

Comment: $Tx=\lim_{m\to \infty} T_m(x)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Hi, thanks! But if thats the case, why cant I say the samething about $T_nx-Tx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the comments above... you can say the same about $T_nx - Tx$, namely that $$||T_n x - T x||_Y\to 0$$ as $n\to \infty$. However, in order to show that $L(X,Y)$ is complete, you need to show that $T_n\to T$ in the **operator norm** i.e.
$$||T_n - T|| = \sup_{||x||_X\le 1} ||T_n x - Tx||_Y \to 0$$
as $n\to \infty$. We use that fact that $Y$ is complete and $T_n$ is Cauchy to acheive this.

Here is a quick recap of the proof just for completeness. Fix $\varepsilon >0$. Since $T_n$ is Cauchy in $L(X,Y)$ we have that $T_n x$ is Cauchy in $Y$ for any $x\in X$ since
$$||T_n x - T_m x||_Y \le ||T_n - T_m||||x||_{X}.$$
Therefore, since $Y$ is complete, for each $x\in X$ we know that $T_nx \to y(x)\in Y$ as $n\to\infty$. It is not difficult to show that the limit $y(x)$ is linear and continuous (and hence bounded) as a function of $x$ and so we suggestively write $Tx = y(x)$. Now for the $\varepsilon >0$ that we fixed earlier, let's choose an *arbitrary* $x\in X$ so that $||x||_X\le 1$. Then we can find $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $m\ge n \ge N$ (note that we can take $m$ arbitrarily large) we have
$$||T_n x - T x||_Y\le ||T_n-T_m||||x||_{X} + ||T_m x - T x||_{Y} \le ||T_n-T_m|| + ||T_m x - T x||_Y < \varepsilon.$$
Since this inequality holds for an arbirary $x\in X$ so that $||x||_X\le 1$, by the property of the supremum, we have that
$$\sup_{||x||_X\le 1} ||T_n x-Tx||_Y \le \varepsilon$$
Which tells us that $T_n \to T$ in the operator norm and so $L(X,Y)$ is complete.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I finally realized that the notation for norms in definition of operator norm in Folland's book are not the same norm.